# Read from docx tables with python-docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx

I am trying to read the C column from a table cell content of a docx file using python-docx library under python 3.7.

[image: Here] Here you can see the table. It has one row and three columns.

I can read the most-left column with `print(doc.tables[15].cell(0,0).text)`, the B column is empty but with `print(doc.tables[15].cell(0,2).text)` I am getting just:
`'   \n\n\n\n    \n'`.

I have tried to read also all the paragraphs or runs but the results are the same.

I don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: Try `print(doc.tables[15].cell(0,2)._tc.xml)` and see what XML is in that cell. It could be the text is "wrapped" in unaccepted revision marks or something like that.